# Change .htaccess filename in XAMPP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp

I'm setting up XAMPP on my computer, and I'm having trouble with my .htaccess files. However, these are configured exactly as I want them for my server, but my localhost needs some different rules. Is there a way for me to make the Apache server look for something like .htaccess.localhost instead, so I can modify my .htaccess for my localhost and server separately?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In config file for Apache you can find next section

```
#
# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

I think this will help you.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I couldn't find it because those lines aren't in there by default. So I just pasted them at the end of the file, restarted the server, and it worked. Thanks!